# Is there any way to clear listview with javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, listview

> ```
> <asp:ListView ID="lvZipcodeFinder"></asp:ListView>
> ```

I am using my listview at the modal popup. So, If modalpopup close and open, listview has to be cleared....
so Is there any way to clear the listview with javascript? It must be cleared with javascript.... please, Help me..

Comment: Can you post the ASPX for the Popup modal? Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: Hi could you post rendered HTML? if it is too big post in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that: (on Server Side *remove the actual items from DOM* )

Just add a hidden button to your .aspx page:

> ```
> <asp:Button ID="btnClearListView" runat="server" 
>               Text="Button" style="display:none;" 
>               OnClick="btnHidden_Click" ClientIDMode="Static" />
> ```

and in your javascript when you call close modal you just use this code as well.

> ```
> document.getElementById('btnClearListView').click();
> ```

and in your code behind for that button you will have something like this:

> ```
>   protected void btnClearListView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         ListView1.Items.Clear();
>     }
> ```

You could do the same at the time of opening a modal-popup as well.

(on Client Side using jQuery)

This is another way to do it but this would only disappear the control rather that removing the actual items from the listview. you should know that if you require to remove a server control you must do it using server side coding.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Submit1").click(function () {
            $("#lvZipcodeFinder_itemPlaceholderContainer").remove();
        });
    });
</script>

<input id="Submit1" type="button" value="Close Popup" />
```

**Make sure the ListView id is match with the javascript code above, you need that _itemPlaceholderContainer afterwards though**